# SimpleCursorAdapter duplicates click action on bindView

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, simplecursoradapter, listviewitem

trying to setOnClickListener on a listView child item to change list item background on click, so i customized SimpleCursorAdapter as below.It works but also changes other list items color that out of screen (8 step down than clicked one, eg: if clicked items parent position is 0 it also changed background at position 7, In the same way for 3 to 10,). i also have a setOnItemClickListener that works fine. Cant get what wrong i did? Thanks in advance.

[image: List view (marked child item on that setOnClickListener)]

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.bbt.alright.imeetup.R;


public class ProgramsCA extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

public ProgramsCA(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_program, parent, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCalV);
    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fTheProgram);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            View parentRow = (View) view.getParent();
            ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
            final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D98BC34A"));
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked "+position , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

And here is my List:

```
public class EventsList extends Fragment {
private SQLiteHandler db;
private ListView lv;
// Store instance variables
private String title;
private int page;


// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static EventsList newInstance(int page, String title) {
    EventsList fragmentFirst = new EventsList();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_event_list,container,false);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.programs_list);

    makeMyList();
    return view;
}

public void makeMyList() {
    Cursor cursor = db.getEventsByDate(title);

    String[] source = new String[]
            {
                    AppConfig.EVENT_NAME,
                    AppConfig.EVENT_TIME,
            };

    int[] toView = new int[]
            {
                    R.id.event_title,
                    R.id.event_time,
            };

    ProgramsCA scA = new ProgramsCA
            (
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_program,
                    cursor,
                    source,
                    toView,
                    1
            );

    ListView myList = lv;
    myList.setAdapter(scA);
    clickMyListItem(myList);
}

public void clickMyListItem(ListView lv)
{
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            int iCol_Name = cursor.getColumnIndex(AppConfig.EVENT_SERVER_ID);
            int sid = cursor.getInt(iCol_Name);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    ItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("icon", (int) R.drawable.ic_action_event);
            intent.putExtra("title", "Program Detail");
            intent.putExtra("s_id", (int) sid);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}



public void myClickHandler(View v)
{
    ListView lvItems = lv;
    for (int i=0; i < lvItems.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        lvItems.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    //get the row the clicked button is in
    RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();

    int c = Color.CYAN;

    vwParentRow.setBackgroundColor(c);
    vwParentRow.refreshDrawableState();
}





}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private selectedItem = -1;
```

then on getView add:

```
if(position == selectedItem)
//set selected background color 
else 
//set normal background color
```

onClick:

```
selectedItem = position;
notifiyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks, but not helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this：

```
private int selectedItemSid = -1;

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCalV);
    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fTheProgram);
    int iCol_Name = cursor.getColumnIndex(AppConfig.EVENT_SERVER_ID);
    final int sid = cursor.getInt(iCol_Name);
    if (sid == selectedItemSid) {
        iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D98BC34A"));
    } else {//set normal background color,assume white
        iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE));
    }
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectedItemSid = sid;
            notifiyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
 }
```